# Beta in Capital Structure

Tags: beta, capital-structure

Can anyone please explain how do I get this:

$$\beta_e = \beta_a +(\beta_a - \beta_d) \times D/E$$

from

$$K_e =K_a +(K_a − K_d) \times D/E.$$

Comment: replace K with BETA?